# Proxy server truncating View State

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

Is there any way I can simulate a proxy server truncating a viewstate?

Comment: Yikes, which proxies do that?

Comment: I wonder why would any sane proxy server truncate anything from the HTML transmitted from the server.

Comment: Based on the research the I have done, some proxy servers will truncate the viewstate if it is too large.

Comment: I guess I can truncate the viewstate variable in the request object efore it loads/validates...Any better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I avoid ViewState client-side entirely by putting it server-side.  The code is about 5 lines long and I've seen a tremendous improvement in performance.

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/robertb/archive/2005/11/16/13835.aspx

You could fake a tampered viewstate easily using fiddler:

http://www.fiddlertool.com/

Comment: There's also a good article on CodeProject about using the Provider model to store ViewState in a database:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/ViewStateProvider.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How have you ascertained it is a proxy server? It doesn't sound likely that a proxy server would truncate parts of the HTML.

However, if ViewState is interfered with then ASP.NET will throw an Invalid Viewstate exception. So, erm,

```
throw new System.Web.UI.ViewStateException();
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555353 - Intermittent Invalid Viewstate Error in ASP.NET Web pages