# Keynote KITE and ASP.NET Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Just had the classic ViewState exception on a live site - "Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate."

This is a two server, load balanced environment and we'd set the `<machineKey>` in web.config on both machines???

The exception we get details the user agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; KTXN) - which I believe is the [Keynote KITE agent](http://forums.keynote.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=90&threadid=428&highlight_key=y&keyword1=KTXN). The problems specifically seems to be that the ViewState is being truncated in requests form this client - anyone seen this before?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the user agent could have been behind a firewall that truncated the ViewState? Rex Lin mentions that possibility in [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1115906.aspx/1), along with a solution based on splitting up the ViewState into separate fields.

Another approach would be to implement [server-side ViewState](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/robertb/archive/2005/11/16/13835.aspx) as suggested by @Nissan Fan here: [Proxy server truncating View State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200814/proxy-server-truncating-view-state)

Neither of which strictly answer the question, but may remove the underlying problem.

Comment: @Neil: Nice one la - does that actually solve the problem?! Click the tick if it does ;)